How can I update my query cache when I recieve this data?
I use infinite scroll and want to update my cache state but I recieve this array:

so how I do it and is there a easiery way ? with this array I have to map through two arrays and then another array.
I recieve this data when I make this:
const prevData = queryClient.getQueriesData<TAllCacheHolidayData>({queryKey: ['all_holiday_tab']});

so is there an easier way to update an state and if no how I update it with these two arrays ?
